# Javascript | Floating point numbers + interval loop

Tags: javascript, loops, numbers, settimeout, floating

I have a floating point number (for example): 0.004178174922295

How could I get the decremental function to make a calculations from this number to 0 in specific amount of time (for example 1 second)?
Thanks.

Expected values:

```
0.004178174922295
0.004178174922294
0.004178174922293
...
0
```

Comment: Also, what's the source of that number? User input, server-side data, some calculations result? I'm asking, because depending on that it might be much better idea to work with integers instead, using all those `0.000...` just to show that number.

Comment: It's just a number (constant).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `0.004178174922294 - 0.000000000000001 !== 0.004178174922293`

Comment: @XTRUST.ORG what are the requirements? is using strings fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **raina77ow** and others pointed out in the comments, [operations with decimal numbers are problematic in JS, approximations are made and the results may be inexact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

A workaround would be turn the infinitesimals into big integral numbers, work with them and convert them back at the end.

Is this what you were looking for? Please let me know.

**EDIT**
You can ask for the countdown to be done in a certain amount of time, it does work with reasonable numbers, but in Javascript [the minimum interval is of 10 milliseconds](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), you can't call intervals shorter than that. With the example number you gave, `0.004178174922295`, it's like counting down from `4178174922295` to zero. That would requiere almost 1325 years in 10 millisecond intervals (if my math is correct, either way I expect you were going to pass a much shorter lapse).

```js
function infinitesimalCountDown(num, seconds) {
  // I create a coeficient to convert the decimal to an int
  // Will be a big number starting with "1" and followed by a bunch of zeroes
  let coefString = '1';
  for(let i=0; i<num.toString().length-2; i++) {
    coefString += '0';
  }

  const coef = Number(coefString);

  // This has the digits from the original original but it's an int
  let counter = Math.round(num*coef);

  // Now I can just treat it as an int and convert it back for the output
  const icdInterval = setInterval(() => {
    counter--;
    console.log(counter/coef);
    if(counter <= 0) clearInterval(icdInterval);
  }, Math.round(seconds*1000/counter));
}

console.log("It works with a short number");

infinitesimalCountDown(0.0041, 10);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("It doesn't work with a long number");
  infinitesimalCountDown(0.004178174922295, 3000);
}, 12 * 1000);
```

If you are fine with the steps being the necessary for Javascript to be able to process it, you can do the following:

```js
function infinitesimalCountDown(num, seconds) {
  let coefString = '1'
  
  for(let i=0; i<num.toString().length-2; i++) {
    coefString += '0'
  }

  const coef = Number(coefString)
  
  let counter = Math.round(num*coef)
  
  let steps = seconds * 1000 / counter
  
  steps = steps < 100 ? 100 : steps
  
  let step = 1
  
  if(steps == 100) {
    step = counter / ((seconds * 1000) / steps)
  }
  
  console.log(step)
  
  const icdInterval = setInterval(() => {
    counter -= step;
    if(counter <= 0) {
      counter = 0
      clearInterval(icdInterval)
    }
    console.log(counter/coef)
  }, steps)
}

infinitesimalCountDown(0.004178174922295, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If you can represent the input number as `number` type (so not have many decimals), you can do this using normal number subtraction.

Here, the important thing is to get the unit to be subtracted. You can get the unit using `Math.pow`.

And from this [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/), it is needed to round the counted number and that can be done using `toFixed` function.

```js
let input = 0.004178174922295;
const decimalCount = input.toString().length - 2;
const unit = Math.pow(10, -1 * decimalCount);

console.log(input);
const loopInterval = setInterval(() => {
  input = Number((input - unit).toFixed(decimalCount));
  console.log(input);
  if (input == 0) {
    clearInterval(loopInterval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

#### And if the input number has many decimals so it is received as `string` type (not able to present using `number` type), it is needed to do the subtraction using string as follows.

```js
const input = '0.0041781749222934534534534535';
const inputArr = input.split('.');

const intNum = inputArr[0]; // Present integer
let decimals = inputArr[1]; // Present decimals after '.'
const unit = 1;

function replaceAt(str, index, replace) {
  return str.substring(0, index) + replace + str.substring(index + 1);
}

console.log(input);
const loopInterval = setInterval(() => {
  let index = decimals.length - 1;
  while (parseInt(decimals[index]) < unit) {
    decimals = replaceAt(decimals, index --, '9');
  }
  decimals = replaceAt(decimals, index, `${parseInt(decimals[index]) - unit}`);
  
  console.log(`${intNum}.${decimals}`);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to complete all the calculations in specific amount of time? For example I want to iterate from maximum value to zero in specific amount of time. Currently it substract 1 value every 1 second.

Comment: From this (https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/Window/setTimeout/#:~:text=Additionally%20a%20setTimeout%20or%20setInterval,the%20window%20is%20not%20focused.), the minimum miliseconds you can set is 4ms. So it won't work for the long numbers like can be described only string.